# Mysql más de una condición en el mismo campo

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE cliente = '1' 
AND marca_pieza_id = '1' OR marca_pieza_id = '5' 
OR marca_pieza_id = '8' OR marca_pieza_id = '11' 
AND sistema_id = '3' OR sistema_id = '16' 
AND estado = '1' AND nombre != '';
```

Está bien realizada esa consulta?, porque "marca_pieza_id" me trae todos, y no solo la "1", "5", "8" y "11", como quiero.

Comment: Dime si la respuesta te sirvio, y en caso de que  la respuesta haya resuelto tu problema te agradeceria que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Disculpá. Si, me sirvió tu respuesta! y la marqué como "aceptada".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla 
WHERE cliente = '1' AND marca_pieza_id in ('1','5','8','11') 
AND sistema_id in ('3','16') AND estado = '1' AND nombre != '';
```

Usa el **operador in**. Este operador devuelve aquellos registros cuyo campo indicado coincide con alguno de los valores en una lista, aquí por ejemplo validamos que el valor del campo **marca_pieza_id** se encuentre en la lista de valores **('1', '5', '8', '11')**, de esta forma compactamos la consulta y no usamos el **operador or**.

También está la negación de este operador, que se escribe como **not in**, y tiene el efecto contrario, es decir devolvería los registros que no estén en la lista de valores a comprobar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo corregí de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT * FROM tabla 
WHERE cliente = '1' 
AND (marca_pieza_id = '1' OR marca_pieza_id = '5' 
OR marca_pieza_id = '8' OR marca_pieza_id = '11') 
AND (sistema_id = '3' OR sistema_id = '16') 
AND estado = '1' AND nombre != '';
```

De igual manera, voy a indagar en el **operador in**. Gracias!